# Laravel 5.5 Not Routing On Live Server

Tags: php, laravel

I have a live server.With apache installed. For some reason it doesn't accept my routes. The main laravel page shows but when you use a root I get:

Not Found

The requested URL /sayit was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at aragonserv.co.za Port 443

When I say "https://example.com/sayit"

Please find below the files I have on figured

File: /etc/apache2/sites-available/ example.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin admin@example.com
        ServerName example.com
        ServerAlias www.example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public
        <Directory /var/www/example.com/public>
          Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride all
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf

        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.example.com [OR]
        RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.com
        RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

File: /var/www/example.com/public/.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

My Routes web.php

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/sayit', 'TestController@sayHello');
```

My Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class TestController extends Controller
{
        //TEST METHOD
        public function sayHello(){
                return echo "Hello";
        }
}
```

Comment: its not an laravel issue. i think the problem is in your htaccess file

Comment: Have you tried accessing Routes from public directory where your index.php file is located to test ?

Comment: It's important to pay attention to the details.  `Port 443`.  Is this your virtualhost for port 443?  Doesn't look like it.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following:

1 - Enable apache rewrite module `sudo a2enmod rewrite` and reload apache.

2 - Files permissions

```
sudo chgrp -R www-data storage bootstrap/cache
sudo chmod -R ug+rwx storage bootstrap/cache
```